# How to tell to pm2 to ignore all errors in scripts locpated at node_modules and subfolders?

Tags: node.js, npm, server, pm2, nvm

I am testing an APP under server enviroment:

- Use of aaPanel or btPanel under ubuntu
- Use of pm2 module
- The app is running but restart on error
- I am using custom error managment and log functions
- I want pm2 just ignore all console.log(error) and errors ocurred in scripts located at node_modules and subfolder

Anny idea?

Thanks for your time and for any help

This is a example of some error log from pm2:

```
2021-03-12T01:52:51: PM2 log: App [MyApp] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
```

And this is a example of error in out log from pm2:

```
Error: /www/wwwroot/apps/MyApp/1.0.0.2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/www/server/nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/www/wwwroot/apps/MyApp/1.0.0.2/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
```

This is a log from console pm2 console in aaPanel or btPanel:

```
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Time                 : Fri Mar 12 2021 00:05:50 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 4.5.5
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 14.16.0
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /root/.pm2
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /root/.pm2/pm2.pid
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /root/.pm2/rpc.sock
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /root/.pm2/pub.sock
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Application log path : /root/.pm2/logs
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Worker Interval      : 30000
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /root/.pm2/dump.pm2
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2021-03-12T00:05:50: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-03-12T00:20:11: PM2 log: App [MyApp] starting in -fork mode-
2021-03-12T00:20:11: PM2 log: App [MyApp] online
2021-03-12T00:21:59: PM2 log: Stopping app:1.0.0.2 id:0
2021-03-12T00:21:59: PM2 log: App [MyApp] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-03-12T00:21:59: PM2 log: pid=95350 msg=process killed
2021-03-12T00:22:24: PM2 log: App [MyApp] starting in -fork mode-
2021-03-12T00:22:24: PM2 log: App [MyApp] online
2021-03-12T00:40:41: PM2 log: Stopping app:MyApp id:0
2021-03-12T00:40:41: PM2 log: App [MyApp] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-03-12T00:40:41: PM2 log: pid=96990 msg=process killed
```

Aditional Notes:

- The app run flawless under local enviroment
- The pm2 is the problem some awfull bad config maybe!
- I run and test the app using 'nodemon index.js' all ok
- I run and test the app using 'node index.js' all ok
- I run and test the app using 'npm start' all ok
- I run npm update all ok
- I run npm audit all ok

Comment: You need to fix your node modules build. You are copying from one architecture to another - you instead need to install modules on the target environment. Bcrypt builds native code as part of its module. You can’t just copy the node_modules folder over.

Comment: Any library should be agnostic to enviroment but that is another history, I will try hard, thanks, at this point I need to reinstall almost any library to global to avoid problems rigth?

Comment: Some libraries include compiled code from C or C++. It’s not about installing globally, it’s that you need to install them on the target vs copying the modules over from your local machine.

Comment: I already installed all libraries in global mode except "bcrypt", for some reason the panel installer in pm2 doesn't install it, could it be something else? but surely the problem is related to that library

Comment: @Joe , I Start session using putty and try to execute the command npm install bcrypt --save in the application directory and it does not recognize the npm command, however the panel appears installed in its latest version, I have trouble so I assume that the binary is in a different route than usual

Comment: All problems gone when I replace the "bcrypt" library with "bcryptjs" no globals need no reinstall need just simple copy and paste node_modules and edit two lines of code to replace ``` require("bcrypt") ```  with ```` require("bcryptjs") ``` nice! but I still want to know how to tell pm2 to ignore console.log () instead of just comment it and also to ignore errors as I am using specialized functions to handle those errors any idea?